# log4j2 RollingFileAppender old file gets removed after 7 rollovers

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I use following log4j RollingFile appender in my webapp.

```
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="logFile"
                 fileName="${env:SYSTEM_LOGS}/${env:LOG_FILE_NAME}.log" immediateFlush="true"
                 filePattern="${env:SYSTEM_LOGS}/${env:LOG_FILE_NAME}.log.%d{yyyy_MM_dd.HH_mm_ss}.%i">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyyMMdd-HHmmss.SSS}|%X{username}|%-5p|%t| %-100m (%c{1})%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy/>
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
```

With `filePattern="${env:SYSTEM_LOGS}/${env:LOG_FILE_NAME}.log.%d{yyyy_MM_dd.HH_mm_ss}.%i"`, when log is rolled over, old file gets renamed to a filename with an index number (specified with %i), so all old files should get renamed and should be preserved.

I rollover the log programmatically with following code.

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger logManagerLogger = LogManager.getLogger();
Map<String, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Appender> appenders = ((org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger) logManagerLogger).getAppenders();
appenders.forEach((appenderName, appender) -> {
    if (appender instanceof RollingFileAppender) {
        LOGGER.info("Switching log for appender " + appenderName);
        ((RollingFileAppender) appender).getManager().rollover();
    }
});
```

But, after 7 rollovers, the existing file gets removed (not renamed according to the specified `filePattern`) and log is continued in a new file.

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set DefaultRolloverStrategy(default is 7), In your config will be:

```
    <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="logFile"
                 fileName="${env:SYSTEM_LOGS}/${env:LOG_FILE_NAME}.log" immediateFlush="true"
                 filePattern="${env:SYSTEM_LOGS}/${env:LOG_FILE_NAME}.log.%d{yyyy_MM_dd.HH_mm_ss}.%i">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyyMMdd-HHmmss.SSS}|%X{username}|%-5p|%t| %-100m (%c{1})%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="100"/>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
```

now, it will have 100 log file to rollover.

Answer (score 1):

If you want unlimited rollingfile,

According to [Log4j2 documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html), from release 2.8, it can be done by setting `fileIndex` attribute to `nomax`. For example:

```
<DefaultRolloverStrategy fileIndex="nomax" />
```